# VB.NET Class and list(of issue

Tags: vb.net, list, class

I'm using couple of custom classes and need to write data in one function and read data in another.
In order to do that, I'm using an XM file.

My issue is when I write the data.

Here is my code:
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System

```
Public Class MainForm

  Public Class MyClass
    Private _id As Integer
    Private _somestring As String
    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            _id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Somestring() As String
        Get
            Return _somestring
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _somestring = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Private Sub mysub()
  Dim ListVar As New List(Of MyClass)

  ' code...code.....code....

   Dim newvar As New MyClass()
   console.writeline("==== within the loop ====")
   For i As Integer = 0 To 2
     newvar.Id = I
     newvar.Somestring = "hello - " & cstr(I)
     ListVar.add(newvar)
     console.writeline("listvar(" & i & ")=" & listvar(i).Id)
   Next
    console.writeline("==== outside the loop ====")
    console.writeline("listvar(0)=" & listvar(0).Id)
    console.writeline("listvar(1)=" & listvar(1).Id)
    console.writeline("listvar(2)=" & listvar(2).Id)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

==== within the loop ====

listvar(0)=0

listvar(1)=1

listvar(2)=2

==== outside the loop ====

listvar(0)=2

listvar(1)=2

listvar(2)=2

I must be doing something stupid but I just figure out what it is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
   console.writeline("==== within the loop ====")
   For i As Integer = 0 To 2
     Dim newvar As New MyClass()
     newvar.Id = I
     newvar.Somestring = "hello - " & cstr(I)
     ListVar.add(newvar)
     console.writeline("listvar(" & i & ")=" & listvar(i).Id)
   Next
```

`newvar` continues to be the same instance, so all three references in the List point to the same instance, and its Id value is what you set it last in your For loop.

Comment: I knew it was simple!

Now that you point it out, it makes perfect sense.

Thanks.